# Select all rows which contains duplicate values in ID and delete them from previous table

Tags: sql

I have a table C which was created as Union of A and B. Simplified version sufficient to address my problem can be created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE C
(
ID int,
String varchar(50),

);

insert into C values (1,'afa')
insert into C values (1,'afa')
insert into C values (2,'afa')
insert into C values (3,'afa')
insert into C values (4,'afa')
insert into C values (4,'afa')
insert into C values (5,'afa')
insert into C values (6,'afa')
```

I need to select all the rows which contains duplicate value in ID column and then most likely I will need to remove rows with those IDs from table B. Table A and B did not contain duplicate values.

the result of select query should be like

```
ID string
1   afa
1   afa
4   afa
4   afa
```

BTW: other columns where ID is duplicated differ slightly so I would not get rid of it using union in the first place

thx

Comment: group by id having count(*) > 1

Comment: this is not what I need I need the result of select query look like I will edit the question

Comment: Why don't you add the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question.. You want to delete ID's from table b that appear on table a? If so you can use EXISTS():

```
DELETE FROM B
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A
             WHERE B.id = A.id)
```

To only select them as @artm suggested:

```
SELECT ID FROM c
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Or again with exists:

```
SELECT ID from B
WHERE exists(SELECT 1 FROM A
             WHERE B.ID = A.ID)
```

EDIT: To get the result you posted, assuming that C table doesn't exists yet:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM B
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM A) t
WHERE t.id  IN(SELECT ID FROM(SELECT ID FROM A
                              UNION
                              SELECT ID FROM B)
               GROUP BY ID 
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks first need to select , question about it and then likely delete

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group by` and `Having` for finding such a duplicates:

```
select id 
from c
group by id
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you need to delete data from table B, please upgrade previous query:

```
delete 
from B
where id in (
    select id 
    from c
    group by id
    having count(*) > 1);
```

UPDATE:
If you want to receive result you listed:

```
select *
from c 
where id in (
    select id 
    from c
    group by id
    having count(*) > 1);
```

Result:

```
ID string
1   afa
1   afa
4   afa
4   afa
```